# How can I use a batch script to remove folder and all of its contents based on folder name in YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I currently use a robocopy batch script to make backup copies of directories, the batch script below creates a folder in the format YYYYMMDD of the current date the script is ran.

Script Below:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

robocopy "\\fsfiles\d$" "D:\Backups\Inc\%datestamp%" /S /W:0 /R:1 /MAXAGE:1 /A-:SH
```

I then use another batch script to remove the backups after 31 days.

Script Below:

```
@echo off
:: set folder path
set dump_path=D:\Backups\Inc

:: set min age of files and folders to delete
set max_days=31

:: remove files from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd  /c del /q @path"

:: remove sub directories from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path
```

While the script to remove the folder and all of its contents based on the date the folder was created works, I would like to change it to remove the folder and all of its contents based on the folder name in date format YYYYMMDD if it's older than 31 days.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is all much easier in PowerShell. I recommend switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial script, there's nothing wrong with using `WMIC` for the date retrieval. However you're using `RoboCopy` already, so you can use that to retrieve the date you require:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do Set "ds=%%A%%B%%C"&GoTo BackUp
Exit /B
:BackUp
RoboCopy "\\fsfiles\D$" "D:\Backups\Inc\%ds%" /S /W:0 /R:1 /MaxAge:1 /A-:SH
```

For you're second script I'd suggest, *as did your first commentor*, using `PowerShell` instead.

Here's an example `.ps1` script which would remove directories with name strings older than 1 month, *(most likely the intention)*:

```ps1
$MonthAgo = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
$Folders = (Get-ChildItem "D:\Backups\Inc" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -Eq $True -And $_.Name -Match '^\d{8}'})
ForEach ($f In $Folders) {
    $FolderDate = Get-Date -Year $f.Name.SubString(0,4) -Month $f.Name.SubString(4,2) -Day $f.Name.SubString(6,2)
    If ($FolderDate -LT $MonthAgo) {
        Remove-Item $f.FullName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

…and similarly to remove directories with name strings older than 31 days:

```ps1
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
$Folders = (Get-ChildItem "D:\Backups\Inc" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -Eq $True -And $_.Name -Match '^\d{8}'})
ForEach ($f In $Folders) {
    $FolderDate = Get-Date -Year $f.Name.SubString(0,4) -Month $f.Name.SubString(4,2) -Day $f.Name.SubString(6,2)
    If ($FolderDate -LT $DaysAgo) {
        Remove-Item $f.FullName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

*The powershell scripts above, were not designed to actually remove the directories, just show you what would be removed. To actually remove them, delete `-WhatIf` from line `6`*

Comment: Thanks for the powershell tip! Is it possible to create a log of the folders that got removed via powershell?

Comment: `Remove-Item` doesn't generate any output, the usual method is to use `Test-Path` and check if it exists shortly afterwards. An alternative would be to output the `-WhatIf` to your log file, then run `Remove-Item` without that option. You could even output the names to the log before removing them. _I'll leave that to you, to research and decide for yourself though, as the late request is technically outside of the scope of your original question_.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "skip=%max_days%" %%d in ('dir /b /ad /o-n "%dump_path%\20*" ') do ECHO rd /s /q "%dump_path%\%%d"
```

would be my choice.

Perform a `dir` in `/b` (basic) mode, showing `/ad` directories only, in `/o-n` reverse-name order. Using the `20*` mask "shows" only directorynames that start `20`.

The first `max_days` lines are skipped when `for /f` processes the `dir` result, so 31 generations remain.

This avoids the date-calculation, which is very complex in batch, but leaves 31 generations, regardless of the length of months and any days that might have been skipped due to holidays, etc.

Comment: This assumes that the OP is backing up every day, _some people have days off_, so it doesn't meet the stated requirements! _I accept that it doesn't delete things which it shouldn't, but it may leave things which were intended to be removed_.

Comment: @Compo: True, but if OP leaves on a cruise, then "31 days" taken literally could remove too *many* backups. It all depends on how literal the interpretation of the time is to be.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution IMHO is NOT TO ask batch to do arithmetic stuff on dates (Aquila non captat muscas :-) )

Try this simple script instead.

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set dump_path=D:\Backups\Inc
FOR /F "Usebackq" %%a IN (`DIR /AD /B /O-N "!dump_path!" ^| MORE +31`) DO (
    echo %%a
)
```

Obviously i put an "echo" instead of the remove command, to let you evaluate how this works. You can then put the deletion command inside the parenthesis.

Substantially, if you are sure your dir names are in the form of YYYYMMDD, it lists them in reverse order, excluding the first 31.

This way has the advantage of keeping the newest 31 Dirs even if your backup script breaks and stop making backup. The other ways you'd have the oldest copies deleted even if there's no new backup to replace them.

Hope this helps

Comment: This assumes that the OP is backing up every day, _some people have days off_, so it doesn't meet the stated requirements! _I accept that it doesn't delete things which it shouldn't, but it may leave things which were intended to be removed_.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Although, if the OP is backing up regularly (let's say twice a week) he can adjust schedule of the deletion batch and the "+31" after the MORE command to get the expected result indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your date format is sortable and comparable I'd use:

```
@echo off
:: set folder path
set dump_path=D:\Backups\Inc
PushD "%dump_path%"

:: set min age of files and folders to delete
set max_days=31

:: Use PowerShell to eval max_days
for /f %%A in (
  'powershell -NoP -Noni -C "(Get-Date).AddDays(-%max_days%).ToString(\"yyyyMMdd\")"'
) Do set PurgeDate=%%A

For /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON "20*" '
) Do If "%%A" Gtr "20000101" if "%%A" Lss "%PurgeDate%" Echo RD /S /Q "%%A"

PopD
```